# Arithmetic progression topology and continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Consider Z with the topology generated by the basis below, with p = 2. That is, the basis elements for this topology are sets of the form

B(a, k) = {a + (2^k)m | m ∈ Z}.

Let f : Z → Z be the multiplication by 2 map, so f(n) = 2n. Prove f is continuous in
this topology

I think f-1(n) = n/2, but that seems to make the function not continuous. For example, if a = 1 and k = 1, we get {...1,3,5...} which when divided by 2 does not give integers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Suppose $k>0$, If $a$ is odd, $f^{-1}(B(a,k))$ is empty. If $a$ is even, $f^{-1}(B(a,k)=B({a\over 2},k-1)$.

If $k=0$, $B(a,k)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $f^{-1}(B(a,k))=\mathbb{Z}$.